# React.js search filtration on the array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a problem with the `search`. It is a front-end search rather than a remote search, I'm using `react.js` because it is a requirement in the problem and created a component named `App`. My task is to display and highlight the matching parts according to the type value.

I will appreciate it. If you provide me a good solution for this.

Let me tell you the whole scenario. I'm dividing this problem into 3 parts.

**Part 1:** *What is the shape of the data?*

The shape of the data is this:

**src/data.js:**

```
export default [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Wordpress',
        list: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Best Mobile App Builder',
                slug: '/'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Best Wordpress Themes',
                slug: '/'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Best Website Creator',
                slug: '/'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Best Wordpress Builder',
                slug: '/'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'SaaS',
        list: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Appointment Scheduling Software',
                slug: '/'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Design Services',
                slug: '/'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Online Cloud Storage',
                slug: '/'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Remote PC Access',
                slug: '/'
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

**Note**:

[image: Search 2 properties]

Basically this is my filter function.

**src/filter.js:**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import match from 'autosuggest-highlight/match';
import parse from 'autosuggest-highlight/parse';

/**
 * Returns the new filtered array with highlighted parts.
 * @param data {Array<Object>} - The collection to iterate over.
 * @param inputValue {string} - The input value.
 * @return {Array} - Returns the new filtered array.
 */
export const filterByNames = (data, inputValue) => {
    // Create a dynamic regex expression object with ignore case sensitivity
    const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(inputValue), 'i');
    const results = data.filter((object) => {
        if (re.test(object.name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return object.list.some((item) => {
                if (re.test(item.name)) {
                    // Calculates the characters to highlight in text based on query
                    const matches = match(item.name, inputValue);
                    // Breaks the given text to parts based on matches.
                    // After that create a new property named `parts` and assign an array to it.
                    item['parts'] = parse(item.name, matches);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return results;
};
```

The search is working fine but facing 2 major issues.

1. When the above match of the `name` property occurs, then it stops and does not go much deeper. The same thing is happening with the nested list `name` property.
2. When the filtration happens behind the scenes we're mutating the original data by adding a new property named `parts` which contains highlighted parts and it is an array of objects. But I don't want to mutate the original data instead wants to return the new filtered array which contains `parts` property.

See this.

[image: Search Overall]

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit search-frontend]

**Part 2:** *Which third-party libraries I'm using for filter and highlighting?*

- [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) string function [escapeRegExp](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#escapeRegExp) for escapes the RegExp
  special characters.
- [autosuggest-highlight](https://github.com/moroshko/autosuggest-highlight) [match](https://github.com/moroshko/autosuggest-highlight#match) function to calculates the
  characters to highlight in text based on the query.

  After that, from the same library [parse](https://github.com/moroshko/autosuggest-highlight#parse) function help us to break the given text to `parts` based on matches. In the end, it will
  return an array of objects with the match string and `highlight`
  boolean flag. So it's easy for us to **bold** the highlighted `parts` on the UI.

**Part 3: App component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { filterByNames } from './filter';
import data from './data';


/**
 * Return the JSX for the List
 * @param data {Array<Object>} - The collection to iterate over.
 * @return {null|*} - Returns the JSX or null.
 */
const renderList = (data) => {
  if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
    return data.map((object) => {
      return (
          <div key={object.id}>
            <h1>{object.name}</h1>
            <ul className="list">
              {object.list.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                      {item.parts ? (
                          <a href={item.slug}>
                            {item.parts.map((part, index) => (
                                <span
                                    key={index}
                                    style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}
                                >
                          {part.text}
                        </span>
                            ))}
                          </a>
                      ) : (
                          <a href={item.slug}>{item.name}</a>
                      )}
                    </li>
                )
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
      )
    })
  } else {
    return null
  }
};

// Main App Component
const App = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const { target } = event;
    const val = target.value;
    setValue(val);
  };

  const results = !value ? data : filterByNames(data, value);
  
    return (
        <div className="demo">
          <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
          <div className="demo-result">
            { renderList(results) }
          </div>
        </div>
    );
    
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Easily could be handled with vanilla javascript, and perhaps ajax with jquery Meaningful comment because react isnt needed for this.

Comment: @GetSet Don't need `ajax` it is not remote search but client-side search.

Comment: @GetSet Yes, don't need `ajax` the whole frontend of the application is in `react.js`. But the `filter` function is the main thing.

Comment: But react like most frameworks *allows* your own solutions where you want to fit them. Looks like your react skills are moderate, as such you could put in a solution that doesn't use react. Ijs

Comment: I have one question about your goal. When the user types `storage`, is it find to list all SaaS items (4 items) and highlight Storage? I don't correctly understand your major question 1.

Comment: @HaydenS. For example: When the user types `wordpress` it will highlight all the `wordpress` words on the data. Another example `best` word which I already showed in the `gif` but it is not highlighting all the `best` words in the data.

Comment: You mentioned that you wish to return a new array rather than a mutated one. This could be easily done by using immutable.js. I'd look into that for this request.

Comment: @FujiRoyale Can we do this with any `lodash` function e.g. `map` to return the new modified array.

Comment: Please review my answer.

Comment: @VenNilson yes. That might be the more accepted way. I just recently played around with immutable. And the lists, maps, etc are really quite nice. They force one to think about things in an immutable way. Ultimately its JS there are probably no less than 1 million ways to do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the revised code.

```
export const filterByNames = (data, inputValue) => {
  // Create a dynamic regex expression object with ignore case sensitivity
  const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(inputValue), "i");
  const clonedData = _.cloneDeep(data);
  const results = clonedData.filter((object) => {
    return object.list.filter((item) => {
      if (re.test(item.name)) {
        // Calculates the characters to highlight in text based on query
        const matches = match(item.name, inputValue);
        // Breaks the given text to parts based on matches.
        // After that create a new property named `parts` and assign an array to it.
        item["parts"] = parse(item.name, matches);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).length > 0 || re.test(object.name);
  });
  return results;
};
```

Forked link here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/search-frontend-forked-e3z55

Comment: Wow. The answer is awesome. Can you please add comments to the code? Is there any other solutions that you know please tell me. I will really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code having solved both

```js
export const filterByNames = (data, inputValue) => {
  // Create a dynamic regex expression object with ignore case sensitivity
  const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(inputValue), "i");
  // since we cannot directly mutate the data object, why not copy it here ? (or if the data is bigger and copying is also not an option then consider using two arrays of data, one for the mutation and one default maybe)
  let data_ = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  // filter and return the newer copy of the object.
  const results = data_.filter((object) => {
    // since we need the highlighting in both cases, on top level, or even in nested level so create separate function for that.
    let highLightEm = (list) => {
      return object.list.some((item) => {
        if (re.test(item.name)) {
          // Calculates the characters to highlight in text based on query
          const matches = match(item.name, inputValue);
          // Breaks the given text to parts based on matches.
          // After that create a new property named `parts` and assign an array to it.
          item["parts"] = parse(item.name, matches);
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
    };

    if (re.test(object.name)) {
      // check for the highlighting in the inner name
      highLightEm(object);
      return true;
    } else {
      return highLightEm(object);
    }
  });
  return results;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/search-frontend-forked-kxui9?file=/src/filter.js

Comment: When the user types `wordpress` it will highlight all the `wordpress` words on the data. Another example` best` word which I already showed in the gif but it is not highlighting all the `best` words in the data.